# ActionBarSherlock Tab Navigation - Same listview data but different layouts for each tab

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

In my app, I have a searchable activity which displays results using a webservice in a listview. I want to add 3 tabs navigation ("liste", "carte" and "photo"). "liste" is the default tab. When clicking on "carte", the results are displaying in a map. When clicking on "photo", they are displayed using another layout. Exactly like this app:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I was able to add the tab navigation but I don't know how to display the results with each tab using different layouts.

```
public class SearchableActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    ListView listViewData;
    ProductAdapter productAdapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cproduct_list);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab1.setText("Liste");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab1);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2 = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab2.setText("Carte");
        tab2.setTabListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab2);

        ActionBar.Tab tab3 = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab3.setText("Photo");
        tab3.setTabListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab3);

        listViewData = (SwipeListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a  FragmentPagerAdapter and for each tab you must create a Fragment.. There is example code available from Android..

If you create in Eclipse a Android Project you can choose about different navigation options. By selecting one of the Tab Navigation options a Project will created with a implemented Tab Navigation as you want..

Comment: Thank you. Things are more clear now. This is how I understand: I have to create 1 activity (the searchable activity which extends FragmentActivity), 3 fragments for each tab, 1 layout that contains FrameLayout, and the 3 layouts for each tab.
 
But my searchable activity calls a webservice and I don't know to handle this. How to pass the webservice data to the fragments?

Comment: You can check this link for passing data to Fragment from activity: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity